# php removing item/variable from php array using button

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Im looking for help with this. I've tried unset and other options and nothing seems to be working. I hate to bother people but ive searched google till the cows come home and im doing it wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$orderArray = $_SESSION['orderVal'];
foreach($orderArray as $orderVal)
{
$valInvent = getOrderInventories($orderVal['invId']);?>

<tr><td><?php echo $valInvent['itemnumber'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $valInvent['description'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $valInvent['cp'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $orderVal['price'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $orderVal['qty'];?></td>
<td></td>
</td>
```

I want to remove an item from this array using one of the variables.

Comment: which array? $orderArray or $valInvent?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

I am using

```
unset($valInvent['itemnumber']);
```

Comment: should i use a button to fire this off?

Comment: Yes, you can or write it where you want to reset. If you want to create new array without item, make new loop and setup new array without item using this code